# deploy BPEL Process on WSO2 Server

Tags: wso2, bpel

I am trying to deploy my BPEL Process on WSO2 server, after generating the .zip file i am trying to upload it on the server using the administration page, but the upload fails and this error appears in the Log file :

> File upload failed :BPEL Compilation Failure!
>
> TID[-1234] [BPS] [2015-10-26 05:50:36,550] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.ui.fileupload.BPELUploadExecutor} - File upload
>   failed :BPEL Compilation Failure!
>   org.wso2.carbon.bpel.ui.fileupload.BPELUploadExecutor.validateBPELPackage(BPELUploadExecutor.java:295)
>   org.wso2.carbon.bpel.ui.fileupload.BPELUploadExecutor.execute(BPELUploadExecutor.java:103)
>   org.wso2.carbon.ui.transports.fileupload.AbstractFileUploadExecutor.executeGeneric(AbstractFileUploadExecutor.java:104)
>   org.wso2.carbon.ui.transports.fileupload.FileUploadExecutorManager$CarbonXmlFileUploadExecHandler.execute(FileUploadExecutorManager.java:392)
>   org.wso2.carbon.ui.transports.fileupload.FileUploadExecutorManager$FileUploadExecutionHandlerManager.startExec(FileUploadExecutorManager.java:276)
>   org.wso2.carbon.ui.transports.fileupload.FileUploadExecutorManager.execute(FileUploadExecutorManager.java:125)
>   org.wso2.carbon.ui.transports.FileUploadServlet.doPost(FileUploadServlet.java:57)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)

I even tried to manually add the file to **repository/deploymen/server/bpel**

but the process still doesn't appear in the List of deployed processes.

I have searched around the web and couldn't find an answer.Any help ?

**EDIT**

This is what i have when i unzip the bpel pack :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the structure of your .zip file. Did you edit an existing bpel pack and re zip it again? If that is the case make sure, that when you unzip it the files are directly listed like below (instead of having another folder within the zip file) . For example if A.zip,

A-|
   a.bpel
   a.wsdl...

Answer (score 0):

Please check your BPEL process again. Specially deploy.xml file. Check the ports are assign correctly.